# Chrome breaks words when each letter is wrapped with a span

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In my HTML, I am individually wrapping each character in each word with a `span`, and then giving each one an `::after` pseudo-element. On Chrome 93, this results in the words breaking once they hit the end of the container. On Firefox 92 and Safari 15, the word doesn't break and instead gets moved onto the next line.

[image: Firefox puts the word on the next line, but Chrome breaks the word in two.]

```css
p {
  max-width: 50ch;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.c {
  position: relative;
}

.c::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="c">s</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">l</span><span class="c">u</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">i</span><span class="c">o</span><span class="c">n</span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c"> </span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">l</span><span class="c">u</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">i</span><span class="c">o</span><span class="c">n</span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c"> </span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">l</span><span class="c">u</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">i</span><span class="c">o</span><span class="c">n</span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c"> </span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">l</span><span class="c">u</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">i</span><span class="c">o</span><span class="c">n</span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c"> </span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">l</span><span class="c">u</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">i</span><span class="c">o</span><span class="c">n</span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c"> </span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">l</span><span class="c">u</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">i</span><span class="c">o</span><span class="c">n</span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c"> </span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">l</span><span class="c">u</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">a</span><span class="c">t</span><span class="c">i</span><span class="c">o</span><span class="c">n</span><span class="c">s</span><span class="c"> </span>
</p>
```

I want the Firefox/Safari behaviour where the word is *not* broken. I tried an assortment of `white-space` and `word-break` values, but I couldn't find something that works. I'm pretty sure the `::after` pseudo-element is the culprit here, since when I get rid of it, the word wraps as expected.

**Is there a way to prevent the word from breaking in Chrome** while keeping the `::after` (or `::before` if that works better), and without needing to wrap each word in a span with `nowrap`?

Comment: Wrap each word in a span, then set that span's `white-space` to `nowrap`?

Comment: Right I thought of that but would like to avoid needing the additional span if possible. If there isn't a good alternative I'll probably just go with that though.

Comment: What are the after pseudo elements eventually to be used for because removing their absolute positioning means the desired word breaking behaviour is seen so it's probably going to depend on whether the extra stuff in the after can be accomodated some way other than position absolute.

Comment: It's supposed to be a vertical bar which represents a typing cursor, as demonstrated in this codepen: https://codepen.io/auroratide/pen/MWoJdda. The original idea behind absolute positioning was so it didn't take physical space which could result in gaps between characters.