# Detect which element flex-wrap affects

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: Typing Game]

I'm making a type test app where I have a caret line "|" moving from left to right.

This is what the rough build of my game looks like:

```css
.words_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.word {
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

.game{
  position: relative;
}
.caret {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 22px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="caret" style="left: 10px;"></div>
  <div class="words_wrapper">
    <div class="word">bob</div>
    <div class="word">about</div>
    <div class="word">us</div>
    <div class="word">know</div>
    <div class="word">computer</div>
    <div class="word">again</div>
    <div class="word">fails</div>
    <div class="word">running</div>
    <div class="word">bob</div>
    <div class="word">about</div>
    <div class="word">us</div>
    <div class="word">know</div>
    <div class="word">computer</div>
    <div class="word">again</div>
    <div class="word">fails</div>
    <div class="word">running</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a state variable to adjust the **left** attribute

```
const [caretPos,setCaretPos] = useState();
```

Then I modify this position based on other factors when typing and apply it in the div style.

```
<div className='caret' style={{left: `${caretPos}px`}>
```

**Now, my question is, How can I detect if my caret is at the end of the line and make it go to the next line**

Notice that the div has a flex-wrap property so it automatically makes the words go to the next line. Is there a way to detect which word is at the end of the line or at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ways of thinking about this problem:

- The first answers your code question directly (how do I detect when the next flex element wraps).
- The second addresses your cursor problem with an alternative approach.

### Detecting a Flex Wrap

You might be able to detect a wrap by using the actual positions of the objects via [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). This function gives you where something is relative to the viewport. Crucially, we know an element "wraps" if its vertical location is different from that of the previous element.

```js
const isWrapping = (previous, current) =>
  previous.getBoundingClientRect().top !== current.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

```js
const isWrapping = (previous, current) =>
  previous.getBoundingClientRect().top !== current.getBoundingClientRect().top

const highlightWrappingElements = (container) => {
  for (let i = 1; i < container.children.length; ++i) {
    const previous = container.children[i - 1]
    const current = container.children[i]
    
    if (isWrapping(previous, current))
      current.classList.add('wrapping')
  }
}

highlightWrappingElements(document.querySelector('#container'))
```

```css
.container {
  width: 30rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: blue;
}

.wide { width: 7.5rem; }
.wrapping { background: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="box wide"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box wide"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box wide"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box wide"></div>
  <div class="box wide"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

In the example, elements that start a new line are orange.

How you would integrate this technique into your problem depends on how your React code is set up, but the idea should be a good starting point.

### Moving a Caret

Your actual goal is to move a caret through a paragraph of letters. To do so accurately, it must:

- Know the length of each letter to position itself accurately
- Know where the end of the line is so it can wrap

Those are non-trivial problems, especially if the box has to resize or the paragraph content is dynamic. That is, if you are trying to position the caret manually with `position: absolute`.

Instead, you might be able to actually *embed* the caret in the text itself.

```
<p>This is s<span class="caret"></span>ome text.</p>
```

This solves the above two issues immediately, as the caret will always be exactly where it needs to be as long as you rerender the node when the caret's position changes.

**Warning:** On Chrome, the caret span breaks the word which results in it wrapping at the end of a line. This can be fixed by, for example, wrapping each word in a `span` set to `display: inline-block`. I have left out how to do that in the code below for brevity.

```js
const paragraph = document.querySelector('#paragraph')
const content = paragraph.textContent

const caret = document.createElement('span')
caret.classList.add('caret')
let caretPosition = 0
const advanceCaret = () => {
  caretPosition += 1
  if (caretPosition >= content.length)
    caretPosition = 0

  paragraph.innerHTML = content.substring(0, caretPosition) + caret.outerHTML + content.substring(caretPosition)
}

setInterval(advanceCaret, 100)
```

```css
.container {
  width: 30rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

p { margin: 0; }

.caret {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.caret::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

I prefer this as it's simple and avoids most of the complexity with manual positioning, but whether it's viable is up to how you are ultimately rendering your paragraph of text.

Comment: Your second example, when the caret gets to the end of the second line, characters from the third line appear at the end of the second line.

Comment: This is wonderful! Thank you so much. 
I think I'll stick with the first approach as I want to keep a smooth animation on my cursor. I don't know if animation can be done with the second approach?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Ah, indeed; turns out this happens in Chrome and not Firefox, and while looking into it I awkwardly [ran into my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121874/chrome-breaks-words-when-each-letter-is-wrapped-with-a-span). Seems like it can be fixed by wrapping each word in its own span to prevent it from breaking.

Comment: And yes, if you want a smooth transition, manipulating the position as you are doing is what is needed.